# Java Web application seems sleep

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-boot

Our application is based on Spring boot(the latest version), everything works as expected after deployed at the server.

However we found that for a certain period(maybe 30 minutes) during which there are no visitors, it will response very slow when you visit the page again. And after the re-first visit, the subsequent requests will response normally. Looks like the embedded tomcat or jvm slept.

What's going on?  How to fix that?

Comment: If DB connection pool is used in your application. A possibility is the connection has been closed by DB server, due to the idle timeout.